# In need of array of post tags

Tags: tags, single

On the single-post page within the loop I need an array of the_tags() which is a string. and get_tags() gives me all of the tags not only this posts. Is there an easy way to get this?

Comment: the function `get_the_tags()` does for a single post, what `get_tags()` does for the site. 

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags
 
 - do you need an array of the tag ids, or a string with a comma-separated list of tag ids?

Comment: get_the_tags() was the exact replacement I needed thanks. if you post as answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the function [`get_the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) does for a single post, what [`get_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) does for the site.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**wp_get_object_terms()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) function:

```
$tags_objects = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag');
```